# Consultation about crystalreport database error

Tags: c#, ms-access, crystal-reports

I try to connect to an Access database using C# and CrystalReports.

One report works excellent, but when I try to connect to a new report I got this error:

```
Logon failed
Details: DAO Error Code: 0Xbdb
Source: DAO.DbEngine
Description: System resource exceeded
```

Comment: How are you running the reports?  Are you closing your connections after finishing?  Post your C# code.

Comment: There are some similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcrystal-reports%5D+log+failed